# How to get a specific field for parsing log files using pandas regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, pandas

i am a beginner python How do I get the IP address, user name, date, time and save it in a csv file? Because it is a 1TB large file, it takes over 30 hours. Is it slow if I use regular expressions? So, how can we analyze with pandas?

I write some Python code for getting ip address only: [very slow]

```
import re
from collections import Counter
import csv
import sys

names_to_check = ('ImapConnMade', 'UserDataException', 'AcctBadPswd')
def read_log(filename):
    rege = r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}'
    with open(filename,encoding='utf-8') as f:
        log = f.read()
        if any(name in log for name in names_to_check):
            ip_list = re.findall(rege,log)
            return ip_list

def counter(ip_list):
    count = Counter(ip_list)
    return count

def write_csv(count):
    with open('/Users/kiya/Desktop/mysql/ipscan/kk.csv', 'w') as out:
        header = ['ip']
        write = csv.DictWriter(out,fieldnames=header)
        write.writeheader()
        for k,v in count.items():
            write.writerow({"ip":k})
if __name__ == '__main__':
    log_file = '/Users/kiya/Desktop/mysql/ipscan/ip2.txt'
    write_csv(counter(read_log(log_file)))
```

my sample log file:

```
20160531 161947365+0900 elim1td001p imapserv 58124 58719 139941482481408 Note;UserDataException(485/968) MBX_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED:{protocolType=[imap], userName=MzQyNQo, password=[MTY2ODgyMDAwOAo]}:AuthenticateAndGetMailboxService\3aPOST:Authenticating Failed.::user=MzQyNQo:cmd=1 LOGIN MzQyNQo MTY2ODgyMDAwOAo:fromhost=4.165.114.31:sid=22e63f2a-0ffa-77bf-352e-001720d50212
```

Comment: Instead of trying to read your file which doesn't fit in your memory at once, you should treat it line by line.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille for using readlines ?

Comment: I think you do not need pandas if you are not using it. Just use [this snippet](http://rextester.com/WHVSO29558) to get and write matches to a file.

Comment: Did it work for you? I mean, writing the values can be done in any way you need, but using `with io.open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fw:
    with io.open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fr:
        for line in fr:` ?

Comment: Did anything work?